# PHP and Redis - Performance - PHP is a Bottleneck

Tags: php, linux, performance, apache, redis

I have set up Redis 2.4 on my Ubuntu Desktop 11.10, 8 cores and 8 GB ram.

Running the redis-benchmark tool I consistently see 100K of SETS and GETS per second with a 4096byte package. Apache will server up 24k of the index.html page per second, so these number are excellent.

In testing the performance on the total stack - Apache - PHP5 (using Fastcgi) and Redis max thoughput is 250 requests per second.

If I comment out the calls to Redis I still get 250 requests per second.

Using htop, CPU usage is 95% PHP and 5% Redis, Apache is hardly visible.

So the question is what should I be realistically expecting the throughput to be with this combination?

Software details:

PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.2.20
Linux 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 20:45:39 UTC 2012 x86_64

Comment: It will depend on what the PHP script will do and the hardware off course. Otherwise nothing really useful can be stated about it.

Comment: Yes - of course - I understand that, however I can add some more info - I compiled phpredis, https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis and managed to lift the request rate to average 2000 per second. I'll strip the php file down to the bare minimum and add functions to see what that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a microframework for PHP instead of bigger frameworks. Also, if you include many PHP files, performance will drop (even with APC). Also, PHP r/s won't match static html r/s.

Comment: Thanks vamur - I did some more research - and found a C based library that improves performance dramatically - phpredis. Its is a PHP extension that has all the functions of the script based frameworks but includes 10 times the r/s.